# Error after upgrading OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

Hi everybody after upgrading from **OpsCenter 5.2.3** to **OpsCenter 5.2.4** I got this error in the log:

```
SchemaAgreementFailed: Failure waiting for schema agreement after schema 
    change CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "OpsCenter"."bestpractice_results"
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: There is a timeout in the schema changes, can you try restarting the daemon to try again?

Comment: im restarting  service and  many times also im  uninstalling    and installing  opscenter the same error i get .

Comment: i found this error also in opscenter.log . Problem while calling DashboardPresetsGetDefaultController (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'  What can i do

Comment: im solving  this problem by remove cluster.conf and drop the opscenter keyspace  bout  when im  change the  strategy_class to NetworkTopologyStrategy i get the same problem ?

Comment: @AtefAzmy Were you able to solve the schema agreement error?